# Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 19 to the 14 allowed

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I am creating a project using angular and node, In my project i have written one function where lot of if and else if statements with multiple conditions. i am getting cognitive complexity issue. I went through some links, but I am not able to understand how should I change my code without affecting users of this method.

```
  if (
      (
        !orderRequest.paymentProvider
        || isAdyenProvider
      )
      && orderRequest.paymentMethod === OrderRequestV2.PaymentMethodEnum.CREDITCARD
    ) {
      this.processPaymentGiftCard(basket,constants.PAYMENT_METHODS.CREDIT_CARD,constants.PAYMENT_METHODS.GIFT_CERTIFICATE,'AdyenCreditCardPaymentMethodService');
    } else if (
      isAdyenProvider
      && orderRequest.paymentMethod === OrderRequestV2.PaymentMethodEnum.PAYPAL
    ) {
      this.processPaymentGiftCard(basket,constants.PAYMENT_METHODS.ADYEN_PAYPAL,constants.PAYMENT_METHODS.GIFT_CERTIFICATE,'adyenPayPalPaymentMethodService');
    } else if (
      (
        !orderRequest.paymentProvider
        || isAdyenProvider
      )
      && orderRequest.paymentMethod === OrderRequestV2.PaymentMethodEnum.INVOICE
    ) {
      this.processPaymentGiftCard(basket,constants.PAYMENT_METHODS.INVOICE,constants.PAYMENT_METHODS.GIFT_CERTIFICATE,'AdyenInvoicePaymentMethodService');
    }  else if (
      orderRequest.paymentProvider === OrderRequestV2.PaymentProviderEnum.COD
      && orderRequest.paymentMethod === OrderRequestV2.PaymentMethodEnum.COD
    ) {
      return this.processPayment(basket,constants.PAYMENT_METHODS.CREDIT_CARD,'GMOCreditCardPaymentMethodService');
    } else if (
      (
        !orderRequest.paymentProvider
        || isAdyenProvider
      )
      && orderRequest.paymentMethod === OrderRequestV2.PaymentMethodEnum.GIFTCERTIFICATE
    ) {
      const giftCardPaymentInstruments = await this.pickPaymentInstruments(basket, constants.PAYMENT_METHODS.GIFT_CERTIFICATE, true);
      return this.getGiftCardsPayments(giftCardPaymentInstruments);
    } else if (
      (
        !orderRequest.paymentProvider
        || isAdyenProvider
      )
      && orderRequest.paymentMethod === OrderRequestV2.PaymentMethodEnum.APPLEPAY
    ) {
      this.processPayment(basket,constants.PAYMENT_METHODS.APPLE_PAY,'AdyenApplePayPaymentService');
    } else if (
      (
        !orderRequest.paymentProvider
        || isAdyenProvider
      )
      && orderRequest.paymentMethod === OrderRequestV2.PaymentMethodEnum.SHOPRUNNER
    ) {
      this.processPayment(basket,constants.PAYMENT_METHODS.CREDIT_CARD,'AdyenShoprunnerPaymentService');
}
```

Comment: For each if statement  - break out into a separate function.  You maybe able to re-use this code blocks too.

Comment: Make it DRY....

Comment: @SteveTomlin : I tried but same result

Comment: @user5798214 - then where is your example?

Comment: The complaint is justified; that's madness. The `else` statements are pointless; each conditional returns. There's chunks of repeated code, there's missing utility methods that **look** like they belong in `orderRequest` (not sure w/o diving in), etc.

Comment: It looks like there's at least one missing abstraction ("how to calculate things based on payment method"). Creating that and moving a lot of this logic to implementations would help. If you don't have decent tests in place add them now.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the size of the main function but breaking complicated if statements into their own functions. Something like this:

```js
const isAdyenProvider = () => 
  getCreditCard(orderRequest.paymentProvider,isAdyenProvider) ||
  getPaypal( 
    isAdyenProvider, orderRequest.paymentMethod,
    OrderRequestV2.PaymentMethodEnum.PAYPAL
  ) ||
  otherMethods() ||
  handleError()
```

Comment: Extra note: This is (almost) the Single Responsibilty Principle. Something should have only one reason for change.

Answer (score 0):

Without deep digging into the logic I think it's possible to start from these suggestions:

1. You can avoid `else` at all:

```
if (condition1) {
  ...
}

if (condition2) {
  ...
}
```

2. Move similar logic to separate function. For example here you have only two differences which can be passed into function as params.
   [image]

3. Some conditions can be moved to variables. For example this part repeats:

```
!orderRequest.paymentProvider || isAdyenProvider
```

4. Destructure all what you need before usage:

```
const { paymentProvider, paymentMethod } = orderRequest;
```

No need to always use full construction like `orderRequest.paymentProvider` or `orderRequest.paymentMethod`.

Comment: With this approcah, now am getting 15 to 14

Comment: Now I think you can see that you use this condition `!orderRequest.paymentProvider || isAdyenProvider` in many branches. Separate other branches, move them to the top. Then It's possible to use early return like `if (!condition) return;` and then you can use for example switch(paymentMethod) instead of ifs. I mean smth like this https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-chaplygin-p5poyw

Answer (score 0):

I would look to do something like the following:

```
const { PaymentMethodEnum, PaymentProviderEnum } = OrderRequestV2;
const { PAYMENT_METHODS } = constants;

const payments_type_map = {
  ['is_ayden-' + PaymentMethodEnum.CREDITCARD] : {
    main_payment_method: PAYMENT_METHODS.CREDIT_CARD,
    allow_giftcards: true,
    payment_service: this.AdyenCreditCardPaymentMethodService
  },
  ['no_pp-' + PaymentMethodEnum.CREDITCARD] : {
    main_payment_method: PAYMENT_METHODS.CREDIT_CARD,
    allow_giftcards: true,
    payment_service: this.AdyenCreditCardPaymentMethodService
  },
  ['is_ayden-' + PaymentMethodEnum.PAYPAL] : {
    main_payment_method: PAYMENT_METHODS.PAYPAL,
    allow_giftcards: true,
    payment_service: this.adyenPayPalPaymentMethodService
  },
  ['is_cod-' + PaymentMethodEnum.COD] : {
    main_payment_method: PAYMENT_METHODS.COD,
    allow_giftcards: false,
    payment_service: this.CashOnDeliveryPaymentService
  },
};

const provider_key = orderRequest.paymentProvider === PaymentProviderEnum.ADYEN ? 'is_ayden' :
  orderRequest.paymentProvider === PaymentProviderEnum.COD ? 'is_cod' :
  'no_pp';

const payment_config = payments_type_map[provider_key + '-' + orderRequest.paymentMethod];
```

With the above probably being in a separate function return the payment config and another function to consume the payment_config object that's been retrieved. Not sure what sonarqube would think of that though.